# cURL fails in PHP, but works in console

Tags: php, api, curl, spotify, access-token

Experimenting with webapp with Spotify API. Satisfied that all data settings on Spotify Developer site OK (client_id, client_secret etc).
When I run the following in the console...

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <the actual access token>" https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V
```

... it works perfectly. Even running the following url directly in the browser works:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V?access_token=<the actual access token>
```

I've tried tagging on the access token to the url in the method below, but no luck. If I try to use the access token in the header and the url, I get an error telling me to use one or the other.

```
<?php
session_start();
class SpotifyClientCredentials
{
    public $url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
    public $client_id = '<the client id>';
    public $client_secret = '<the client secret>';
    public $token = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['token'])) $this->token = $_SESSION['token'];
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $enc = base64_encode($this->client_id. ':' . $this->client_secret);
        $header = "Authorization: Basic $enc";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //workaround prevent CA error
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [$header],
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials'
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($result === false)
        {
            print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }else{
            $data = json_decode($result,true);
            $this->token = $data['access_token'];
            $_SESSION['token'] = $this->token;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    public function request($requestUrl)
    {
        if(!$this->token) $this->connect();
        $header = "Authorization: Bearer {$this->token}";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => $requestUrl,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //workaround prevent CA error
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [$header]
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($result === false)
        {
            print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }else{
            $data = json_decode($result, true);
            print_r($data);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }

}

$spfy = new SpotifyClientCredentials;
$spfy->request('https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/4aawyAB9vmqN3uQ7FjRGTy');
```

Getting rid of `CURLOPT_POST => true`, gives an **502 Bad Gateway**.
I get no response / output whatsoever with the code, as is, above.
As mentioned, tagging on the access token to the requestUrl:

```
CURLOPT_URL => $requestUrl . '?access_token=' . $this->token,
```

gives the following curl response:

```
Array ( [error] => Array ( [status] => 400 [message] => Must not use more than one method for including an access token ) )
```

If I then comment out the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, I once again get no response.
The access token seeems valid, as when I don't include it, I get an error message. Truly at a loss - any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST => false`

Comment: Hi Viney - thanks for the response, but when I do that I get 502/Bad Gateway. First it told me I had an expired token! When I got a new one, I got the 502. Really puzzled.